# Deploying Jakarta EE 9 on JBoss 7.4

Tags: hibernate, jboss, migration, jboss7.x, jakarta-ee-9

For my application we have migrated everything to Jakarta EE 9 so renaming every namespace from “javax” to “jakarta” and also update hibernate from 5 to 6. My problem is that it needs to deploy on JBoss 7.4, is it possible to make use of the “deployment-structure.xml” to make it possible to deploy it on JBoss 7.4? or is that impossible to make it?

Have tried excluding modules but with no success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss EAP 7.4  is Java EE 8 /JakartaEE 8 certified so a Jakarta EE9 application won't deploy on it. For Jakarta EE 10 you should use JBoss EAP 8

Comment: So that means even with deployment-structure excluding modules/sub-system it’s impossible? Because Jboss 7.4 supports Java 17 and if you want to compile your application with java 17 doesn’t that mean you need to use the “jakarta” namespace?

Comment: I don't see how Java 17 and Jakarta EE are related except that some versions of Jakarta EE require a minimal Java version

Comment: Oh my bad, I have 2 different thoughts mixed. Seems like that for JBoss 7.4 is not possible to use the “jakarta” namespace. Thanks for helping and confirming that is not possible.